# How to sort factor levels in a table output in R?

Tags: r, sorting, r-factor

Suppose I have two binary variables:

```
group <- rbinom(100,1,0.6)
y <- rbinom(100,1,0.3)

table(group,y)
         y
    group  0  1
        0 26 13
        1 42 19
```

How to table out or sort the table output in this format:

```
     y
group  1  0
    0 13 26
    1 19 42
```

Comment: You could do `table(group, y)[1:2, c(2,1)]` - if you want it sorted on some criterion, you'll have to tell us what that criterion is - increasing leading diagonal, column with smallest minimum on the left, ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what bigger problem you are trying to solve, either one of these approaches might be helpful. For reference, here is what I get initially:

```
> set.seed(1)
> group<-rbinom(100,1,0.6)
> y<-rbinom(100,1,0.3)
> 
> table(group,y)
     y
group  0  1
    0 28 15
    1 42 15
```

You can redefine `y` to be a `factor` with your own choice of ordering of the factor levels and *then* tabulate:

```
> table(group,factor(y,levels=c("1","0")))

group  1  0
    0 15 28
    1 15 42
```

Or you can run the `table` as above and *then* sort the columns of the output:

```
> table(group,y)[,c("1","0")]
     y
group  1  0
    0 15 28
    1 15 42
```